# How can I set the first link in my nav menu to simply be a drop-down to some other pages

Tags: navigation, hierarchical, menus

I want to have a set of ~3 pages in a subdirectory called "about"

```
example.com/about/history
example.com/about/program
example.com/about/coaches
```

I don't want any `about/index.html` page, I just want "about" to be the label of the drop-down menu. The pages will be just regular WordPress pages.

I don't need help writing the HTML/CSS, I just need to know what files to edit and how to set it up in the WP admin area.

Hope my first post makes sense. This is my first WordPress project. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the wordpress Menus under Appereance -> Menu and wp_nav_menu instead of wp_list_pages in your theme. If your theme is recent, changes are that you are using it now.

Under Appereance -> Menu

- Create a menu, label il "Site menu"
- Create a **custom link** About, and assign it # as destination link
- Drag and drop your about pages after About

See this page of the codex on the [menus](http://codex.wordpress.org/Appearance_Menus_SubPanel)